# Printing a Temp Tower using MakerBot Replicator+

Tags: makerbot, temperature

I am a newbie to 3D printing. I have MakerBot Replicator+ with tough smart extruder in my possession. I want to print a temp tower. However I think I am stuck with Makerbot's software and I don't know how to print one with this since all other examples on internet are mostly on Cura. Is there a way to print temp tower using Makerbot's software? If not could you explain the other alternatives step by step?

Comment: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/7346/ answers your question for Cura. If you look at the G-code, you can even do it yourself by inserting G-code lines at the correct layer height with your file generated by MakerBot software. This could therefore be a duplicate question.

Comment: Hi theycallmefm and welcome to SE.3DP! I would have to agree with @0scar that unless someone can post an answer explicity showing how to do this using Makerbot software, then this question is probably, unfortunately, a duplicate of [How does one use a heat tower?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/7345/4762).